# iOS app feed is timing out

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, ios-app-feed

When trying to get the feed in iOS app, it's loading for about a full minute then stop with a generic error message, leaving me with a blank screen.

Accessing the sites is working fast and fine.

When will we get the feed back?

Version: 0.1.20

**Edit**: looks like it's working for others, but still... I'm sure it's not working for me.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] on my end, seems to be loading fine. Is everything else working?

Comment: @Tim yep, replying now from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved now after closing the app and reopening, action which I did more than a few times before without any luck.

Dunno what was going on, will keep an open eye and of course if anyone else experience the same thing please leave a comment.